# Add dynamic fields in forms (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, forms, dynamic

I have a form defined as:

```
class testForm(forms.Form):
    book = forms.CharField(label='Book:', widget=forms.TextInput())
```

and I am trying to add dynamic fields in forms. which means next to the textbox there is a button, if a click the button, a new textbox comes out under the original textbox, and this form is only one form.

In my template:

```
<table>
   {{form.as_table}}
   <table class = 'request'>
         {{form.as_table}}
   {#  <input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()"/>#}
   {#   <span id="response"></span>#}
   </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </table>
```

I do not want to change my template, so I'm trying to use js to complete it.

```
var countBox = 1;
var boxName = 0;
function addTextBox(){
   boxName = "textBox"+countBox;
   document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<br/><input type="text" 
   id="'+boxName+'" value="'+boxName+'" "  /><br/>';
   countBox += 1;
 }
```

But it's not doing what I want, Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: attach screenshots what you have now "it's not doing what I want,"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is fine for you but you can try to use a page with one form that gets all new books added and shows an additional form.
In basic, when you add a new book via form, it will refresh the page with ajax, the form will not go anywhere and your book will be in database so will be shown in same page.

This is basic code for that:
views.py:

```
def all(request):
    obj = Books.objects.all()
    ...
```

template:

```
<div id='books'>
{% for o in objs %}
    {{ o }}
{% endfor %}
    <form method='POST' action='#' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        // your form
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        <table class = 'request'>
            {{form.as_table}}
        {#  <input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()"/>#}
        {#   <span id="response"></span>#}
        </table>
        <br>
        // end of your form
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </table>
        <input class="ui button" type='submit' value='Add Skill' /> 
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#addform").submit(function(e) {
          var url = $(this).attr('action');
          var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: formData,
                   async: false,
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false,
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                   $("#books").load("# #books");
                   }
                 });
                e.preventDefault();

            });    
</script>
```

If I would encounter same issue, I would go with that but it's your decision of course.

Comment: thanks you, but this is not what i need.I do not want to get the data from database in a loop, but is trying to dynamic add "charFields" in the front-end and input the data by users then submit the form. get the data from front-end and store into db.